# Uploading files using SCP using phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, scp, phpseclib

I need to create 2 functions: one to upload files using SFTP and another using SCP. I'm using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) and the `put` method; I believe I have the SFTP function done.

Now, I'm trying to do the SCP function. Per http://adomas.eu/phpseclib-for-ssh-and-scp-connections-with-php-for-managing-remote-server-and-data-exchange/, it seems like the following are the things I need to do:

```
In case of SCP:
1. Including the needed file: include('/path/to/needed/file/Net/SFTP.php');
2. Creating object and making connection:
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('host');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'password')) { exit('Login Failed'); }
3. Reading contents of a file: $contents=$sftp->get('/file/on/remote/host.txt');
4. Copying file over sftp with php from remote to local host: $sftp->get('/file/on/remote/host.txt', '/file/on/local/host.txt');
5. Copying file over sftp with php from local to remote host: $sftp->put('/file/on/remote/host.txt', '/file/on/local/host.txt');
6. Writing contents to remote file: $sftp->get('/file/on/remote/host.txt', 'contents to write');
```

I need to do #5, but it looks like what I did for SFTP. SFTP and SCP aren't the same, right? Is the same code correct? If not, how do I do SCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the SCP is completely different protocol to the SFTP.

The phpseclib now supports the SCP in recent versions (since version 0.3.5, released in June 2013).

Alternatively, use the PHP PECL SSH2 functions for SCP upload/download:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php

Comment: So the referenced site is wrong. It did SFTP (like I did), but called it SCP. I used phpseclib in order to avoid having to configure the SSH2 functionality (phpseclib says it's a pure PHP implementation). Any alternative solutions to SCP?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "It did SFTP (like I did), but called it SCP.". Where do you want to avoid configuring SSH2? On client side? IMO, you do not need to configure anything on client side, not even with the PHP PECL functions (well, you need to install the PECL package, but that's similar with phpseclib). Alternative to SCP: It was your requirement to use SCP/SFTP. If you want to know other options, give us your constraints.

Comment: Wow. It ask about SCP but the code posted is using SFTP. Read line one of CODE, you will see "In case of SCP" and just next line is telling you howto sftp. Anyway, neubert has updated you :)

Actually phpseclib is the best way to do those ssh things from PHP, and the unique way when you dont have ssh access.

Answer (score 7):

As noted by neubert, phpseclib has SCP support now through the `Net_SCP` class.

You instantiate an `Net_SCP` object by passing it a `Net_SSH2` or `Net_SSH1` object in the constructor, and can then use the `get()` and `put()` methods to download or upload files via SCP.

Here's a simple example script showing me SCPing a file from my local machine to a remote AWS instance.

```
<?php

    set_include_path(get_include_path() .
                     PATH_SEPARATOR .
                     '/home/mark/phpseclib');

    require_once('Crypt/RSA.php');
    require_once('Net/SSH2.php');
    require_once('Net/SCP.php');

    $key = new Crypt_RSA();
    if (!$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('my_aws_key.pem')))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load key");
    }

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('54.72.223.123');
    if (!$ssh->login('ubuntu', $key))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to login");
    }

    $scp = new Net_SCP($ssh);
    if (!$scp->put('my_remote_file_name',
                   'my_local_file_name',
                   NET_SCP_LOCAL_FILE))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to send file");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

phpseclib recently added SCP support:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SCP.php